# Jasmine Testing ForEach and getting cannot read property ''forEach''

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I'm testing a method that pushes a property to my array... but having the error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

How can I fix this?

Note: I'm testing basically a method to use a mat-autocomplete on mu HTML, so the forEach provides data to the autocomplete

**Spec**

```
mockCustomer = [{
      'id': "45831a77-5fee-49f0-8c87-3de1e881fcd1",
      'name': "John Doe",
      'alias': "John",
      'isEnabled': true,
      'updatedOn': "12-12-2020",
      'updateBy': "Daniel"
    },
    {
      'id': "c5c90f2e-b712-43a0-bf8d-0fdfe9c07076",
      'name': "Jeff Doe",
      'alias': "Jeff",
      'isEnabled': true,
      'updatedOn': "10-12-2020",
      'updateBy': "Daniel"
    }]

it('should push on Customer', () =>{
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'pushOnCustomerNames').and.callThrough();
    component.pushOnCustomerNames();

    mockCustomer.forEach(element =>  {
      mockCustomer.push(element.name)
    });

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
```

**Component**

```
pushOnCustomerNames() {
    this.customerNames = [];
    this.customer.forEach((customer: CustomersViewModel) => {
      this.customerNames.push(customer.name);
    });
  }

getCustomers() {
    this._managService.getCustomers().then(customerResponse => {
      this.customer = customerResponse;
      this.pushOnCustomerNames();
      this.filterCustomers();
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.toastr.error(err);
    })
  }

filterCustomers() {
    this.filteredCustomer = this.formFilter.get("customerName").valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filterCustomer(value))
      );
  }

_filterCustomer(value: string): string[] {
    return this.customerNames.filter(customer => customer.includes(value));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

where you define mockCustomer ??? I don't see. If you don't define, you can't use forEach on undefined

Edit:

Look im trying to recreate your error:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyPU8.png)

[image]

I have the same error:

[image]

The problem is because i put value in mockCustomer in afterEach, you need put vmockCustomer value in beforeEach, like this:

[image]

I show in console mockCustomer values.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any problem. Maybe you initialice mockCustomer in afterEach?

Comment: It looks like my previous code, but still not working

Comment: Can you add photo of all spec.ts?